# blender set custom UV through GeoNodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, baking

I created a GeoNode setup to generate a mushroom, i also created a procedural shader to go with it in order to have have a fully procedural mushroom setup.

Now, i want to bake all that procedural stuff to individuals textures and meshes. Baking the texture maps isn't an issue, but i struggle with the geoNodes.

My issue is that i want to create a few variations of the mushroom model using differents seeds for the geoNode setup. The same goes for the textures.

Now i want to bake everything in a way that every texture works with every model. To do that, i need all my UVs to be the same, but if i use the UV unwrap node, first the UV doen't looks good, but also, they are note the same for every model.

The way i usualy create custom UVs in geoNodes is using the store attribute node. But for my project, this doesn't work because i need to alter the real UV of the model, not just an arbitrary attribute.

I hope someone knows a solution. Also, if you have another idea to bake my models and textures, feel free to tell me.

PS: here is the result of my geoNode setup if you are wondering what they looks like (my setup only generate 1 mushroom, but i duplicated it):[image: mushrooms in a grass field]

Comment: what Blender Version are you using? this is impressive for turning the uv attribute to a real uv. there are different ways in different Blender Versions

Comment: another question:  is topology the same on all of the mushrooms? meaning the same vertices faces etc... but they could be displaced or deformed; I'm just wondering if the topology is the same. (If this is the case you could seriously simplify what you need to to the get the same uv's.)

Comment: Yes the topology is the same, also i found how to set the UV from the geonodes, I will reply to my own question incase someone need the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found how to do it, as i thought you need to use the store named attribute node, with the data type set to 2D vector and the domain set to face corner. That way when you click the box for the name of the attribute, your UV map should appear.

Here is an image of the node:

[image]

Comment: this worked for you? I thought the issue was that the uv wasn't correct and not that you didn't have a uv at all.